# Use Worksheet Calculate to automaitcally sort values derived from formula

Tags: excel, vba

I want to sort rows automatically based on values in Column C, which are derived from a formula and will change. So far, I have:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("C140:C143"), Range (Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Call Test

    End If

End Sub

Sub Test()
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C140:C143")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("A140:I143").Sort Key1:=Range("C140:C143"), _
        Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    End If
End Sub
```

This works well to automatically sort values when those values are inputted manually. How can I convert this to Worksheet Calculate to account for values derived from formulas?

Comment: Is there a variable named `Target` that is accessible inside the `Test()` method? Please note that while debugging, it's very important to remove/comment any `On Error` statements (specially `On Error Resume Next`), otherwise, things could be going wrong and you wouldn't know.

Comment: `SelectionChange` gets triggered when the user make a selection, not when values are changed...

Comment: You can use the `Worksheet_Calculate` event.